# Google Docs paste, using formatting of destination document

Tags: google-docs, formatting, copy-paste, font

I want to copy/paste a bunch of content from one Google Doc to another.  The two documents have different formatting (particularly fonts for Headings).

If I do a regular paste (ctrl-v), the headings all come in with the font of the source document.  If I use ctrl-shift-v, it pastes as plain text without any formatting at all.

What I really want is for the paste to use the heading font settings of the destination document. I believe this is similar to the Mac's "Paste and Match Style" option.  I don't own a Mac, so I can't test if that works on a Mac, but regardless, I need this to work on Windows and Linux in Chrome.  Is there a way to this in Google Docs that works across browsers and OS's?

If that is not possible, is there a way (after doing a regular paste) to highlight the newly-pasted section with the source doc's formatting and make Google Docs UPDATE it with the current document's format?

Right now, the only thing that I've been able to figure out to do is to highlight each and every heading, change it to "normal text", and then change it back to the correct heading type.  This works, and uses the updated style, but it's very tedious to have to do this to every heading individually.

Answer (score 0):

Paste regularly, then select all and press C-\ in order to remove styling. This is different from C-S-v in that it doesn't remove structure (headings, titles, etc).